# karnel dead in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to import the tensorflow2 module using jupyter notebook after installing through anaconda.I have able to import once after which kernel is getting dead repeatedly. 
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vNLC.png)

Comment: Tensorflow2 doesnot have

Comment: Python 3.8 supports tensorflow2. whereas tensrflow2 doesn't support the module tensorflow.Session() . To execute the Session module I have created an environment using Anaconda prompt say myevn with basic python version  3.6 or below, the try to install tensorflow1.16 (a lower version ) and carry on your project